# How to get data from database to view page in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fetch, laravel-5.4

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to view my data in database from my view page (`listpetani.blade.php`).

Here is the code of my project:

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><strong>No</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Nama Petani</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Alamat</strong></th>
        <th><strong>No. Handphone</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Lokasi</strong></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

PHP:
In my `listpetani.blade.php` I have an empty table and I want to show data from  [database tbl_user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJcU9.jpg):

```
Route::get('listpetani', function () {

  $petani = DB::table('tbl_user')->pluck('id_user', 'username', 'alamat', 'no_telp', 'id_lokasi');

  return view('listpetani', ['petani' => $petani]);

});
```

And the table in my page: [view in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8NEU.jpg)

I want to show all the data from database into my view in laravel 5.4. Can anybody help me?

Comment: before return to view can you check result set using did($petani);

Answer (score 12):

[SOLVE]

Thank you guys, I already solve this problem

This is the solved code

web.php (routes)

```
Route::get('listpetani', function () {

    $petani = DB::table('tbl_user')->get();

    return view('listpetani', ['petani' => $petani]);
});
```

and in my `listpetani.blade.php`

```
@foreach($petani as $key => $data)
    <tr>    
      <th>{{$data->id_user}}</th>
      <th>{{$data->nama_user}}</th>
      <th>{{$data->alamat}}</th>
      <th>{{$data->no_telp}}</th>
      <th>{{$data->id_lokasi}}</th>                 
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: can you help for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893651/undefined-variable-uprofile-laravel-5-4

Comment: That's great but it's advised not to use DB class in Route file. This may make your application vulnerable.

Comment: this "solution" is really bad

Answer (score 5):

You can get data from database in view also

```
@php( $contacts = \App\Contact::all() )  
@php( $owners = \App\User::all())  

<select class="form-control" name="owner_name" id="owner_name">                           
    @foreach($contacts as $contact)
      <option value="{{ $contact->contact_owner_id }}">{{ $contact->contact_owner }}</option>
    @endforeach                            
</select>
```

It would be better if you pass data from controller to view.

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

Checkout the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: You can send data from controller via compact function e.g. :
$owners = \App\User::all()
return view('viewowners', compact('owners'));

Answer (score 4):

In your controller:

```
 $select = DB::select('select * from student');
 return view ('index')->with('name',$select);
```

In Your view:

```
@foreach($name as $data)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $data->id}}</th> <br>
    <th>{{ $data->name}}</th> <br>
    <th>{{ $data->age}}</th> <br>
    <th>{{ $data->address}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can use @forelse loop inside laravel blade

```
@forelse($name as $data)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $data->id}}</th>
    <th>{{ $data->name}}</th>
    <th>{{ $data->age}}</th>
    <th>{{ $data->address}}</th>
</tr>
@empty
    <tr><td colspan="4">No record found</td></tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@foreach($petani as $p)
 <tr>
     <td>{{ $p['id_user'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $p['username'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $p['alamat'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $p['no_telp'] }}</td>
     <td>{{ $p['id_lokasi'] }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: try $p['id_user'] instead of $p->id
_user, for all the values

Answer (score 2):

**In side controller you pass this **:

```
$petanidetail = DB::table('tb1_user')->get()->toArray();
return view('listpetani', compact('petanidetail'));
```

**and Inside view you use petanidetail variable as follow**:

```
foreach($petanidetail as $data)
{
echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Undefined variable: petanidetail

that's the error message if i change with your suggest

Comment: you should pass petanidetail with view return as follow above in controller

Answer (score 1):

I hope you already know this, but try use Model and Controller as well,
Let the route take the request, and pass it to controller
and use Eloquent so your code can be this short:

```
$petani = PetaniModel::all();
return view('listpetani', compact('petani));
```

and instead using `foreach`, use `forelse` with `@empty` statement incase your `'listpetani'` is empty and give some information to the view like 'The List is Empty'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$petani = DB::table('tbl_user')->pluck('id_user', 'username', 'alamat', 'no_telp', 'id_lokasi');
return view('listpetani', ['petani' => $petani]);
```

on your view iterate `$petani` using `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($petani as $data)
{
    echo $data->id_user;  // $petani is a Std Class Object here
    echo $data->username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct, I just want to add one more thing, if your database field has html tags then system will print html tags like `< p >` for paragraph tag. To remove this issue you can use below solution:

You may need to apply `html_entity_decode` to your data.

This works fine for `Laravel 4`

```
{{html_entity_decode($post->body)}}
```

For `Laravel 5` you may need to use this instead

```
{!!html_entity_decode($post->body)!!}
```