# undefined variable uprofile laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel framework 5.4 and write following controller class:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
 public function index(){
      $uprofile = DB::table('user_profile')->find(Auth::id()); 
   return view('folder.profile')->with('uprofile',$uprofile);
 }
```

route is:

```
Route::get('/','ProfileController@index');
```

At view I'm using

```
@foreach($uprofile as $profile)             
    $profile->id
    @endforeach
```

What seems wrong here?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: undefined variable uprofile

Comment: Make sure you file is ending in `.blade.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `index()` method to :

```
public function index(){ 
    $uprofile = DB::table('user_profile')->where('userid','=',Auth::id())->first(); 
    return view('CityOfWorks.profile')->with('uprofile',$uprofile); 
}
```

Also in `view`

```
@foreach($uprofile as $profile)             
    {{ $profile->id }}    // Blade views in curly braces
@endforeach
```

Comment: this still shows error undefined variable uprofie at `@foreach($uprofile as $profile) ` line

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add $ symbol before uprofile in inde.php. Edited now.

Comment: Tried this?
Add `dd($uprofile);` just above `return view (.....);` and check if the variable contains value.

Comment: Add the above code and see what&#39;s displaying when you refresh `localhost` in browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152941/discussion-between-muhammad-muazzam-and-sreejith-bs).

Answer (score 0):

in your index method , just remove $uprofile

```
return view('folder.profile')->with('uprofile');
```